# Recurring job in Hangfire works intermittently

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hangfire

I have 3 websites configured in IIS which use the same application pool. Each use the same code base (by nature the database is different for each client) and execute a hangfire recurring job each day. Now for 2 of the websites I don't have any problems but for one of the websites, the job does not run each day. Since the job starts immediately when a user access the website, this makes me think that the application pool is suspended and it is "awaken" when the user access the website.

I have already implemented the instructions http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.html so that the application is always running. As I mentioned it works fine for the other 2 and it is just for 1 website where it does not work always. Has anybody else encountered such things before? Or does Hangfire is showing signs of instability where the same code runs perfectly fine for 2 and intermittently for 1.

Thanks

Comment: Does each website have it's own hangfire database instance?

Comment: Why can't you have separate app pools? That's kind of what they're for.

Comment: 1) yes they have separate hangfire instances 2) I have already have separate app pools but it did not change anything

Comment: Is the same version of the job code deployed to each website?

Comment: yes "Each use the same code base"

Comment: Sorry, another question, is the app pool on the third server actually crashing, or just not starting when jobs are queued?

Comment: Like do you see any WAS-releated errors in the logs?

Comment: Thanks Tom. Not sure where third server came into being because there is only one server. Thanks for trying to help though

Comment: It might be that the application pool dies down when it is short of resources and the job doesn't kicks in. The solution could be to recycle the app pool. Another explanation could be that the OS is short of resources and does not start the apps which have been idle for longer time even though the apps are configured to never sleep. I would be trying the recycling solution first and see the result. Also see https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/recurring-job-does-not-run-sometimes/1860

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked this question on the hangfire forum and someone suggested the server itself did not have reosurces enough to run everything and would force-sleep inactive apps even when told not to in the config. Although there was nothing to suggest anything supporting or contradict it. I thought this was the case as the problem mostly occurred on weekend. What I am doing now is to ping the application every hour so the application pool remains active - this mechanism is incorporated within the website and is also scheduled through Hangfire. This has solved the problem and I have not had a single failure since. See https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/recurring-job-does-not-run-sometimes/1860 for further details.